# C# Win Forms: Keep a control's background color when GotFocus

Tags: winforms, controls

I use C# with Win Forms and I try to change the  backcolor of some textboxes...it's not a problem to set the backcolor to something like

myText.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

However, when the textbox gets the focus the backcolor is replaced by grey windows standard color.....

Is there a way to keep the backcolor of a textbox once it was set even if he textbox gets the focus?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697766/windows-application-change-textbox-backcolor-on-focus

Comment: Not really, I understand that I could use GotFocus or LostFocus events to re-set the backgroundcolor...but I wonder if there is away to keep the background color once it was set without using events.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? For me, the out of the box settings in winforms textboxes doesn't overrule my back color. i.e. I can't reproduce the problem you're describing.